# Table data is coming as empty in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json

I am new to React. I am trying to create a table. I was able to fill table header but in table body i am not able to fill the rows and data.

This is actual data -

```
 const [batsmanAgainstTeamContent, setBatsmanAgainstTeamContent] = useState([
    {
      ball: "20",
      runsOffBat: "32.0",
      striker: "abc"
    },
    {
      ball: "38",
      runsOffBat: "68.0",
      striker: "xyz"
    },
  ]);
```

I think problem is in the below snippet -

```
const tdData =() => {
    return batsmanAgainstTeamContent.map((item) => {
      return (
        <tr>
          {
            Object.keys(item).forEach((key) => {
            return <td>{item[key]}</td>
          })
          }
        </tr>
      )
    })   }
```

In the following, ThData() works fine but tdData() does not -

`

```
return (
      <Container>
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>{ThData()}</tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{tdData()}</tbody>
        </table>
      </Container>
```

edit: It works when using map instead of forEach

Comment: `forEach` doesn’t return anything.  Use `map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need to use map instead of the forEach

```
    {
        Object.keys(item).map((key) => {
             return <td>{item[key]}</td>
        })
    }
```

Comment: damn it worked. Thanks alot. Can you suggest some good tutorial about arrays, maps and other related stuffs?

Comment: @ereh I would suggest you study all the different methods available and the examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map since this is a definitive source.  If you really want to die in study the specifications https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-262/

Comment: I prefer you this article.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-foreach-and-map-loop-in-javascript/